# Take vs. Take over

Tags: phrasal-verbs

In the context of customer support, when a support agent starts working on new ticket and marks it as hers; What would be the correct form to describe this action?

Would it be correct to call it "take" when it is a new ticket and "take over" when it was already taken?

Could it be always "take over" regardless of not having ever been taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take over would generally refer to taking control from another who had earlier taken the ticket. The term "Take over" is an abbreviation for "Take over control". This is different than "Take" something no one else has taken yet.